# How to Convert a manual steering system into autonomous steering system, the should have the ability to steer in both manual and autonomous mode

Tags: automotive-engineering, actuator

What kind of actuator might be used to covert a manual steering system to Autonomous steering system.

Currently, I am having a small buggy with manually steering, containing a steering ratio of 4:1. I was trying convert the manual steering system to steer automatically. But, the point here is, the system should have the ability to switch from manual mode to autonomous mode using a switch mechanism.

As of my research, I am able to find the actuator that makes the steering system to run in autonomous mode, but I am not aware of the system to be made, that could switch it again from autonomous mode to manual mode.

One more challenge is that, I don't want to change my steering gear ratio.

I thought of using a BLDC motor with integrated controller, but confused with the disengagement mechanism while switching from autonomous mode to manual mode and also the facing issue to find the placement of this motor.

Is there any alternative? or any other system that could help my steering system to steer in both manual and autonomous mode with proper positioning of the actuator.

What might be the specifications to be considered for the selection of actuator and how to find them?

Comment: many vehicles have steering assist mode these days ... examine the system they use

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you will need a clutch that automatically disengages when you turn the wheel manually.

There are clutch type mechanisms that could engage only when torque is applied by the steering servo, but I think these are likely to create a lot of backlash for the steering servo. That would make it difficult to control.

Another option is to use a steering servo which is easy to back drive. Something with a high KV and low gear reduction. However, even if it *can* be back-driven, I think the additional resistance on the wheel will be annoying when driving manually.

Using a clutch that is disengaged by a switch or torque sensor on the steering wheel eliminates drag in manual mode, while giving a rigid coupling in automatic mode. The only downside is that it could jam, preventing you from steering manually. You could combine this with a servo that's at least somewhat back-drivable for safety?

Answer (score 1):

Kits are available that will allow you to adapt a commercial steering column steering actuator for your buggy. To make it autonomous you would merely feed it a fake steering wheel torque signal.

https://www.ultimatepowersteering.com.au/electric-power-assisted-steering-columns/

etc

Comment: What I could do to steer the buggy in manual condition when EPAS is fitted? I wanted a mechanism that switches from autonomous to manual mode whenever it is needed, just by operating a switch or toggle.

Comment: Use an assist calibration with very low levels of assistance, just enough to overcome the friction and inertia of the EPAS.